# How to launch application with Theme.Material on older devices

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

How can I run my app on `pre-v21` devices?

```
compileSdkVersion  'android-L'
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 'L'
```

I'm only using the `Theme.Material` on `v21`. I'm NOT using the `v20` support library, I'm using `com.android.support:support-v4:19.+`

When running the application from Android Studio it says that the device in not compatible:

```
{compatible=NO, reason=minSdk(API 20, L preview) != deviceSdk(API 16)}
```

From where is it taking the `minSdk 20`?

EDIT:

The reason this is happening could be (if verified) that

> If you compile against a preview SDK (android-L), the build tools will
>   lock minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to that same API level. This
>   results in the produced application being unable to be installed on
>   devices running older releases of Android, even if your application
>   isn't doing anything specific to L.

Source: [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/297xli/howto_use_the_v21_support_libs_on_older_versions/)

Comment: Can you create a dependency report? From command-line Gradle, it would be **`gradle dependencies`** (or **`./gradlew dependencies`**). Not sure how you get to it from within AS itself.

Comment: I'm having some problems in creating this report, I'll keep trying.

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong. I run the script from the project root directory, it create a report with "no configurations".

Comment: Try running it from within a module rather than the root, and see what you get.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you compile against a preview SDK (android-L), the build tools will lock `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to that same API level. This results in the produced application being unable to be installed on devices running older releases of Android, even if your application isn't doing anything specific to L.

Version 0.11 of the Android Gradle Plugin turned on a new Manifest Merger by default, and it allows us to do some [nifty](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger) stuff. So you have to add yo your `AndroidManifest.xml` file a uses-sdk node that simply specifies a `tools:node` attribute.
This specific configuration tells the manifest processor to replace any attributes from `uses-sdk` nodes in lower-priority manifests (such as library manifests) with the attributes in the `uses-sdk` node with the `tools:node="replace"` attribute. Since Gradle also inserts `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` from your `build.gradle` into this `uses-sdk` node, that's all you really need to add.

So your `AndroidManifest.xml` file should look somehing like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="net.eringle.android.ldemo">

    <uses-sdk
        tools:node="replace" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Now you should be able to run your application on any device supported by your minSdkVersion, while taking advantage of the neat new views and utilities in the support lib!

---

Next, I've modified the Android L platform slightly to hide the fact that it's actually a preview platform from the build tools. You can download it from either of these two mirrors:
[mirror #1](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3kP5OEGFYUBZWxacV9jVjVKOGs), [mirror #2](https://mega.co.nz/#!hlp1XTAC!seD3n0x9dkTyR29c7HxNE6XkHXtmpjfcbYrfntVOXmY).

Extract the archive into the platforms directory where you have your Android SDK installed. You'll notice I've named it `android-21` and set the API level to `21` as well. Instead of referencing `L` or `android-L` in your `build.gradle`, just use `21`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'net.eringle.android.ldemo'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    ...
}
```

Now when you build and try to run the application, you should be able to send it to older-platform devices without any issues. Have fun playing with L while retaining backwards-compatibility!

---

Obviously, the workarounds provided above are hacks at best. Please star this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72453&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars), as it seems to be the closest to the heart of the problem (if the Android team even deems it a problem at all).

**All the credits go to [EddieRingle](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/297xli/howto_use_the_v21_support_libs_on_older_versions/)**

Comment: @DavidCorsalini take a look at [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/297xli/howto_use_the_v21_support_libs_on_older_versions/) reddit post.

Comment: Using the modified platform (android-21) works. If you want, edit this answer or create a new one, I'll accept it.

Comment: @DavidCorsalini I edited the answer as you suggested.

Comment: The modified platform still does not work for me (android-21). I still got Failed to find target 21, as it said when trying with  compileSdkVersion '19'. What could be the problem?

Comment: Going to File->Project Structure, and changing the "Compile Sdk Version" from there did the trick for me. So the solution works.

Comment: I should also note that using the android-21 as 'Compile Sdk Version' does not change the status bar color, although android:colorPrimaryDark is defined in the material theme. To see this feature in action, you should use an L device (or emulator) and compile sdk set to android-L

Comment: See my answer below for a new alternative as of version 0.13 of the Android Gradle plugin.