# uses-sdk cannot have tools:node attribute

Tags: android, material-design

I am using the latest Android Studio 1.2.2. While trying to set AppTheme to Theme.Material [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449428/how-to-launch-application-with-theme-material-on-older-devices) to support for older versions too(other than API 21) and many other solutions on the internet I did everything that was written. I made a different values folder named values-v21 and styles.xml in that folder. Then I wrote `<uses-sdk tools:node="replace" />` , the build gave me an error saying:

```
Error:(6, 5) uses-sdk element cannot have a "tools:node" attribute
Error:(6, 5) Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
```

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk element cannot have a "tools:node" attribute.
>   Here is my app.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.amangrover.finalapp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

I thought this problem was fixed for newer versions of Android Studio?

Comment: That question and answer are about last year's L Developer Preview and are not especially relevant for production shipping versions of Android. Just get rid of the `tools:node` attribute, as it is not needed.

Comment: So how can I add Backward Compatibility to my app?

Comment: Since you have not explained what you think is not backwards compatible, nobody is going to be able to help you with that. If your specific concern is `Theme.Material`, use a different base theme on older devices -- your phrasing of your question suggests that you are already doing this.

Comment: You can also have material design compatibility using the new design library "com.android.support:design:22.2.0" and the AppCompat theme. Take a look at http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html and https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this lines in your project's AndroidManifest.xml file to uses-sdk tag like this:-

```
 <uses-sdk 
   tools:node="merge"
   android:minSdkVersion="14"
   android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
```

And also add the tools name space in manifest :-

```
 <manifest 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" .....
  .../>
```